# New Sklearn syntax

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

How could I rewrite this code, so it would work with the sckit-learn 0.22 version?

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoderlabelencoder = LabelEncoder()

x[:,0] = labelencoder.fit_transform(x[:,0])

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categories = 0)

x = onehotencoder.fit_transform(x).toarray()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to know what problem you try to solve because it is not clear what your code was supposed to do.

One thing is sure, you should not use a `LabelEncoder` to encode your data (i.e. `X`) and instead use directly the `OneHotEncoder`. So to one-hot encode a matrix of categories:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

X = np.array(
    [['a', 'b'],
     ['b', 'a']],
    dtype=object
)

encoder = OneHotEncoder()
X_trans = encoder.fit_transform(X)
print(X_trans.A)
```

and you will get:

```
[[1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0.]]
```

If you want to apply the encoder only on a subset of columns, then you need to use the `ColumnTransformer`

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder


X = np.array(
    [['a', 'b', 1],
     ['b', 'a', 2]],
    dtype=object
)

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    [('cat-encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0, 1])],
    remainder="passthrough"
)

X_trans = preprocessor.fit_transform(X)
print(X_trans)
```

and you will get something like:

```
[[1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1]
 [0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 2]]
```